# iPad and Android phone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud, android

Okay, I've got a problem. So I'm going to get a new phone, the Samsung Galaxy J5 (2016), because I'm just tired of my iPhone 4 not being up to date anymore. But my iPad (mini 2) is synced with my iPhone, like the same apple ID, same apps, maybe the same bill. If I've got my Samsung, my iPad won't sync with that, so I can't use my iPad anymore, what do I do?! Do I have to get a new simcard for one of them, a new number (I probably don't want to transfer my data from my iPhone to Samsung because it's just way to much with 8.000 photos), do I have to get a new number? Help

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two things here:

- the SIM in your iPhone is tied to whatever contract you have with your carrier. Transfering this SIM to a new phone should be possible without much hassle (you may need to get a new physical SIM card maybe if the Samsung uses a different format than your iPhone). Moving the SIM card to a new phone will *not* impact the data stored on either the iPhone nor the iPad
- Your apps (and photos if you use iCloud) are tied to your Apple ID. If they are already synced between the iPhone and the iPad, they will still be available on your iPad after moving from iPhone to Samsung. The photos (and any other data tied to your Apple ID) will not be available on the Samsung phone though

PS: If you look for ways to sync data between the iPad and the Samsung phone, please search the site for previous questions or ask a new one. It might help to be rather specific about the kind of data you want to sync, solutions for photos may very well differ from syncing contacts or accessing iCloud mail from Android.